# Subject verb agreement in case of sentences having "along with"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

In my text, for the question, **The dog along with his master ___ for a walk.**,
the answer is marked as **"are going"**

And for another question, **The dog, along with his master, ______ for a walk.**,
the answer is marked as **"is going"**

I think both sentences are the same and that the usage of comma in the second sentence is unnecessary. Since 'along with' is not a coordinating conjunction, the part before it, is to be considered subject. So I feel "is going" should be the answer. Am I wrong? Please clarify

Comment: The questions are traps. When you see the side comment *along with* enclosed in parens, you can ignore it as a secondary remark. But when it pairs two subjects into a plural, you need a plural verb.

Comment: The answers provided as explanations for closing  this question do not apply fully to it; this question should be reopened so as to allow me to post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"'along with', 'as well as', and 'besides' do not behave in the same way as the conjunction 'and' when it comes to subject-verb agreement (even though they have roughly the same meaning or function). Ignore these expressions when determining whether to use a singular or plural verb"

https://awelu.srv.lu.se/grammar-and-words/common-problems-and-how-to-avoid-them/subject-verb-agreement/subjects-containing-along-with-as-well-as-and-besides/